# existe a possibilidade de redimensionar uma arte ASCII em HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, ascii

Estou meio confusa, usei um [site](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20) pra gerar umas artes em ASCII e quando coloquei no HTML ficou maior do que eu esperava

CÓDIGO HTML:

```html
<main class="main_is">
        <section class="mainsec1">
            <div class="mainsecdiv">
                <h1>
                    <pre>          
 ██ ▄█▀    ██▓ ██▓
 ██▄█▒    ▓██▒▓██▒
▓███▄░    ▒██▒▒██▒
▓██ █▄    ░██░░██░
▒██▒ █▄   ░██░░██░
▒ ▒▒ ▓▒   ░▓  ░▓  
░ ░▒ ▒░    ▒ ░ ▒ ░
░ ░░ ░     ▒ ░ ▒ ░
░  ░       ░   ░  
                  
                    </pre>
```

RESULTADO NA PÁGINA:

[[image: ASCII]
<sup>clique para visualizar em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQET0.png)

E toda vez que tento redimensionar com CSS ou com o próprio HTML normalmente não acontece nada '-'

Comment: Já que é um texto ASCII, usar o `font-size` não funciona? `font-size: .75rem` vai usar 75% do tamanho da fonte "root".

Comment: @CypherPotato testei, realmente já resolve!

Comment: fiz um teste com um novo ASCII usando o `font-size` e funcionou,o problema aparentemente era o estilo da fonte que usei,por algum motivo '-